# Prevent Visual Studio from closing editor windows on project reload? (after "hg up" or similar)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, version-control

I have just started using Hg. It is so much more awesome than SVN for me, and I'm sure Git is just as awesome ;-)

Anyway, since I've started using Hg I've found myself jumping around branches (both anonymous and named) a good bit and, of course, the ".SLN" solution file and ".CSPROJ" project files are in the repository.

Now, all is well and good, and Visual Studio 2010 detects the changes and prompts to reload the files/project as appropriate. However, *whenever is the project is reloaded all my editor windows are closed* -- and this is quite an annoying affair, to have to reopen the windows again!

The question is then:

**How can I make VS persist my "state", such as open editor windows, *across* automatic project reloads?**

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have the solution user settings in Hg as well. If you remove those from Hg, everything should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked and the ".SUO" (user settings?) file isn't under revision control and isn't updated when I switch branches. The problem seems to be related to the when the project file is updated. For instance, I add a file to the project in branch A (and commit the change), then switch to branch B (where the file is not in the project), which results in the project file being updated: in this case all the windows are closed. I suspect it happens for any project-file modification.

Comment: (Followup) This behavior is triggered when VS "detects a change" to the project file and the project is "reloaded". It has nothing to do with the presence (or absence) of user settings or other files :(

Answer (score 2):

A while back, Scott Hanselman introduced a VS add-in for the exact same problem. Please, take a look here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingWorkspaceReloaderAVisualStudioAddInToSaveYourOpenFilesAcrossProjectReloads.aspx